# Default method execution order (Ex:- POST vs perform_create)in Django rest framework class based Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning DRF and I have come to the point of View creation using mixins and GenericView. What I want to understand is, In what order are the methods executed?

Lets say I am creating a view like this.

```
class MyView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def perform_create(self...):
        ....(some code)
```

So, for a POST request which method is executed first and why? When I actually tried this the perform_create got executed first, And I want to understand why POST did not get executed first.

I am sure I missing something here, And I am looking for some document on this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Viewset's post method just calls a CreateMixin's create method, which gets a data from request, from HTTP POST method, and then serializes and validates the data, and then calls perform_create, which actually creates the model object and writes it to database.

You can see it here:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py

and here: 
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py